# RCurl Twitter Streaming API Keyword Filtering

Tags: r, curl, twitter, rcurl

I saw this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797688/post-request-using-rcurl) but I have not been able to adapt the answer to get my code to work.

I am trying to filter on the term bruins and need to reference cacert.pem since for authentication on my Windows machine.  Lastly, I have written a function to parse each response (my.function) and need to include this as well.

```
postForm("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json", 
       userpwd="user:pass",
       cainfo = "cacert.pem",
       a = "bruins",
       write=my.function)
```

I am looking to stay completely within R and unfortunately need to use Windows.

Simply, how can I include the search term(s) that I want such that the response is filtered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so I've looked at what you're doing, and some of what you're working on may be helped by examining the [Twitter API methods](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track), although it can be difficult to figure out how to translate some of the examples into R (via the RCurl Package).

What you're currently trying is *very* close to what you need to do, you simply need to change two things.

First of all, you're querying the url for the random sample of statuses. This url returns a random sample of roughly 1% of all tweets.

If you're interested in collecting only tweets about specific keywords, you want to use the filter API url: "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"

After changing that, you simply need to change your parameter from "a" to "postfields", and the parameter you'd be passing would look like: "track=bruins"

Finally, you should use the getURL function, to open a continuous stream, so all tweets with your keywords can be collected, rather than using the postForm command (which I believe is intended for HTML forms).

so your final function call should look like the following:

```
getURL("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json", 
   userpwd="Username:Password",
   cainfo = "cacert.pem",
   write=my.function,
   postfields="track=bruins")
```

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating twitter, use the `twitteR` package.

```
library(twitteR)
searchTwitter("bruins")
```

You can include other parameters (like `cainfo`) in the call to `searchTwitter`, and they should get passed `getForm` underneath.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am looking to hook into the streaming API, not the search API.  The twitteR package is great, but currently does not have capabilities to handle streaming responses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Streaming API is currently included in twitteR - the search api is different (it's backward looking, whereas streaming is "current looking").

From my understanding, streaming is quite different to how lots of APIs work typically work; rather than pulling data from a web service and having a defined object returned, you're setting up a "pipe" for Twitter to push data to you and you then listen for that response.

You also need to worry about OAuth I think (which twitteR does deal with).

Is there any reason that you want to keep in R? I've used python successfully with the Streaming API and a package called tweepy to write data to a MySQL database and then use R to query and analyse the data.

Comment: I want to stay within R mostly because it's the only language I know, but I also will be doing the analysis in it as well.  The RCURL package seems to be robust, so I am sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, twitteR did not talk to the streaming API. Moreover, as far as I know, very few publicly-available Twitter Streaming API connection libraries in *any* language honor Twitter's recommendations on reconnecting when Streaming disconnects / throws an error.

My recommendation is to access Streaming via a library that's actively maintained, write the re-connection protocol yourself if you have to, and persist the data into a database that handles JSON natively. I'm about to embark on a project of this nature and will be writing the collector in Perl, doing my own re-connect logic and persisting into either PostgreSQL or MongoDB. Most likely it will be MongoDB; PostgreSQL doesn't get native JSON till 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, I know, but you'll want to use the "streamR" package for access to Twitter's streaming API.