# twitteR first example

Tags: r, twitter

I am starting with twitteR . I followed the official guide and I did not receive any error during the configuration.

(the official guide http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/vignettes/twitteR.pdf)

When I try to run the first example I receive an error.

```
> cred$handshakeComplete
[1] TRUE
> cranTweets <- userTimeline('cranatic') 
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

Probably I am making something wrong.

Can anyone help me?

SOLUTION!!!

the problem was that instead of repeat all the procedure I loaded the RData saved the first time. 
So I think that every times we need to repeat all the procedure described in 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/vignettes/twitteR.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the very first lines the official guide you mention

```
This package is intended to be combined with the ROAuth package as as of
March 2013 the Twitter API requires the use of OAuth authentication.
```

It's not an error. You need to provide the relative credential.

Comment: Michele thanks for the answer. This is my first time with ROAuth. The official guide http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROAuth/ROAuth.pdf   is not really clear.  How can I do the authentication?

Comment: @Donbeo these may be helpful [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058485/oauth-with-twitter-streaming-api-in-r-using-rcurl), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed)