# Non-character argument in R

Tags: r, oauth, handshake, twitter-r

While using `twitteR` package for R, I am getting the following error

```
Error in strsplit(response, "&") : non-character argument twitter
```

when trying to send my oauth credentials using this code

```
cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL, accessURL=accessURL, authURL=authURL)

cred$handshake(cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package="RCurl"))
```

If I use `http` instead of `https`, I am geting  an error

`Error: Forbidden`

I am working on a Windows machine.

Comment: You are getting `strsplit` error for which command? Question is not very clear please provide more information...

Comment: I am getting that for the handshake command

Comment: You are connecting secure connection you have to use HTTPS, normal HTTP as error suggest forbidden for connection...

Comment: But if i use https i am getting the non character argument error. Some people have suggested using http as a solution for that, but it is not working

Comment: [**This answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15062370/1478381) of mine might be of some help...

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I am getting the same error, I am already using the same code. Here is my [code](http://www.hastebin.com/fezogunivo.hs)