# Posting data to web forms using submit buttons from R

Tags: r, post, web

I would like to post data to a web form from R, and retrieve the result. Is this possible at all?

In particular, I would like to pass a text file to this website
http://ionspectra.org/aristo/batchmode/
and retrieve the result.

The post method the website uses is

```
<form action="../batchreport/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='d9c49e206913e5d8b515bc9705ca2e09' />
```

First I would like to check the radio button "format" to Tab-delimited:

```
<input type="radio" name="format" value="tsv" /> Tab-delimited <br/>
```

Then I would like to upload a given file:

```
<input type="file" name="batchfile" size="20"><br/>
```

Then have the submit button clicked:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ontologize!" />
```

And finally have the resulting text file be retrieved.

Question is, can this be scripted from R, and if so, using what package?
Can it be done using `RCurl`'s `postForm` perhaps? But if so, what would be the syntax in this case?

Any advice welcome!

cheers, Tom

Comment: Have a look at package [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/).

Comment: Ha but then the website has to be made with Shiny, no? The website isn't mine, so not much control on that side...

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797688/post-request-using-rcurl

Comment: Also, try `POST(...)` and `upload_file(...)` in the [httr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little trickier than normal since it's a Django website, and we need to deal with Django's Cross-site Request Forgery protection by generating a CSRF token.

Here's how to do it with `httr`, using the example file provided [here](http://ionspectra.org/static/aristo/example.txt):

```
library(httr)
csrf <- GET(url='http://ionspectra.org/aristo/batchmode/')$cookies$csrftoken
res <- POST(url='http://ionspectra.org/aristo/batchreport/', 
            body=list(batchfile=upload_file('example.txt'),
                      format='tsv',
                      csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrf))
out <- read.delim(file=textConnection(content(res)), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The `GET` call generates the CSRF token, which is needed for the subsequent POST call.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and does not require the GET request. Basically, the ionspectra website plants a cookie when you access the webform, and sends that cookie back to the server in a hidden variable when you SUBMIT. Then the server compares the two. The code below spoofs the cookie using `set_cookies(csrftoken=...)`, to be the same as `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in the body of the POST. As you can see, the token can be just about anything.

```
library(httr)
# download example dataset and save as file "example.txt"
data <- readLines("http://ionspectra.org/static/aristo/example.txt")
file <- writeLines(data,"example.txt")
# POST request; z$content is the returned content, in raw format
z <- POST(url="http://ionspectra.org/aristo/batchreport/",
       set_cookies(csrftoken="arbitrarytoken"),
       body=list(csrfmiddlewaretoken="arbitrarytoken",
                 format="tsv",
                 filter="filter",
                 submit="Ontologize!",
                 batchfile=upload_file("example.txt")))

df <- read.csv(text=rawToChar(z$content),header=T,sep="\t")
head(df)
#   scan.       title score    ChEBI_ID         ChEBI_Name  N   AUC Est..Precision Correct.
# 1     8 CHEBI:34205 0.781 CHEBI:53156 polychlorobiphenyl 24 0.990              1     True
# 2     8 CHEBI:34205 0.755 CHEBI:35446     chlorobiphenyl 27 0.990              1     True
# 3     8 CHEBI:34205 0.708 CHEBI:22888          biphenyls 38 0.943              1     True
# 4     8 CHEBI:34205 0.698 CHEBI:36686        chloroarene 40 0.966              1     True
# 5     8 CHEBI:34205 0.694 CHEBI:36820      ring assembly 49 0.827              1     True
# 6     8 CHEBI:34205 0.681 CHEBI:50887          haloarene 44 0.955              1     True
```