# How can I send an R file through the web server using java?

Tags: java, r, web

I have a Java web application running.

Now, I have this R sample script:

```
zz <- file(outputTarget, "w")  
cat("TITLE extra line", "2 3 5 7", "", "11 13 17", file = zz, sep = "\n")
cat("One more line\n", file = zz)
close(zz)
```

When "outputTarget" = `D://R-Stuff//dataOut.txt` the file is created fine.

Now, I need to send this file to my web server.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to change "outputTarget" to `http://myhost:8080/myapplication/mystrutsaction/dataOut.txt` but I'm sure this will not work because Struts cannot handle this.

What I need to do (in generic way, how can I handle a file saved to URL in Java Web application)?

Comment: I need the server side stuff. To handle things like `file = new File("http://myhost:8080/myapplication/mystrutsaction/dataOut.txt"); fop = new FileOutputStream(file);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you are trying to send a file from R to a web service. So R has to generate a POST request. May be [POST request using RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797688/post-request-using-rcurl) is the answer

Comment: You get it right. I'll take a look and post the results soon.

Comment: The best answer seemed to relate to the [httr library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html)

Comment: Yes. This is just what I need. Unfortunately my windows environment does not allow me to test this right now since httr not came by default and I have no curl installed, but I can see it will work.