# How to pass a variable using url to another shiny app in R?

Tags: html, r, shiny-server

I have one script which plots the graph for any category type say A,B & C ,i am using "textinput" for entering desired category. Now i want to pass this selected category to another script through URL. This script should take that value and do calculations. How can i pass variables from one shiny script to another as input?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many different ways for sending data via URL.

This is a very primitive example of a dispatcher app, using HTTP GET via `readlines()` for sending some tiny data with Shiny to a remote URL.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32874169/2381339), you can read how to parse the data from the query string when creating the receiver app.

```
library(shiny)

dataToBeSent <- list(
  "someVariable" = "myValue",
  "anotherVariable" = "anotherValue"
)

ui <- shinyUI(
  titlePanel("Simply sending some data via HTTP GET")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  sendData <- function ( listData, url ){
    print("Server says: Let's pass data to a remote url!")
    url <- paste0( url,"?",paste(paste( names(listData),unname(listData),sep="=" ),collapse="&"))
    readLines(URLencode(url))
  }
  sendData( dataToBeSent, "http://www.example.com/shinyApp/"  )
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, if you want to share large amounts of data, it might be better to use a shared database or to [use an HTTP POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046474/2381339) instead.