# How to make a POST request with header and data options in R using httr::POST?

Tags: r, httr

I am trying make a POST request with data and header information using `httr::POST`. I can see [how to make a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797688/post-request-using-rcurl), but I am unable to get it to work with curl's data (`-d`) and header (`-H`) options.

This works perfectly in my terminal (obviously with different data/api, but exactly the same format)

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Fred", "age": "5"}' "http://www.my-api.com"
```

#### Question

How can the above POST request be made (with headers and data) using `httr::POST` ?

#### What I've tried so far

```r
library(jsonlite)
my_data <- list(name="Fred", age="5") %>% toJSON

post_url <- "http://www.my-api.com"
r <- POST(post_url, body = my_data) # Data goes in body, I guess?
stop_for_status(r)
```

I get

```
Error: Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

Inspecting `r` further

```
r
Response ["http://www.my-api.com"]
  Date: 2019-07-09 17:51
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<EMPTY BODY>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? `?httr::POST` references `httr::add_headers`, which has examples, as does the [intro vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html)

Comment: This works for me. Maybe it's your package versions? I have httr 1.4.0, jsonlite 1.6, curl 3.2

Comment: @camille thank you. I had checked both but hadn't realised `add_headers` worked with functions other than `httr::GET`. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this; with content type and headers added:

```
link <- "http://www.my-api.com"
df <- list(name="Fred", age="5")

httr::POST(url = link,
           body =  jsonlite::toJSON(df, pretty = T, auto_unbox = T),
           httr::add_headers(`accept` = 'application/json'), 
           httr::content_type('application/json'))
```