# How to pass an array of string in body in httr::POST

Tags: r, rest, post, httr

I am trying to pull some json body with passing an array of string numeric in `httr::POST`.This has to be an `array`. For instance,
`body = toJSON(x=list('_id'="1"), auto_unbox=TRUE)` did not work.

How do I pass an array of string numeric like above in the body?

```
res <-httr::POST(url=some url, 
                 httr::add_headers(
                   "Accept"= "application/json",
                   "Authorization" = my Token, 
                   "Content-Type"= "application/json"),
                 body = ????, #how do i pass ["1"]
                 endoce = ???)
content(res,as = 'text')
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958500/how-to-make-a-post-request-with-header-and-data-options-in-r-using-httrpost/56964855#56964855

Comment: I wanted to AVOID passing JSON. Anyway, I was able to figured out the solution.

Comment: perhaps post your solution then so as to help others?

Comment: `myarr <- c("1", "2")
`
`httr::POST(
    url = some_url,
    httr::add_headers(
      "Accept" = "application/json",
      "Authorization" = my_token,
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    ),
    body = paste0("[", toString(myarr), "]")
  )
`