# API authentication in R

Tags: r

I am building an R package for fantasypremierleague

I want the json from here : https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/my-team/965197

But, to access this I need to login first.

The login url is 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/'

I could get this to work using request package in Python.

I am trying to use httr package in R. However, since the api url and login url are different, *authenticate()* does not work.

Below is the python code that works. How can I translate this into R?

```
import requests
session = requests.session()

url = 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/'
payload = {
 'password': 'pass',
 'login': 'email',
 'redirect_uri': 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login',
 'app': 'plfpl-web'
}
session.post(url, data=payload)

response = session.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/my-team/965197')


print (response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958500/how-to-make-a-post-request-with-header-and-data-options-in-r-using-httrpost/56964855#56964855), you can then add within the `add_headers()` your `Authorization` and `AUTH` headers.

Have a look if that works